# Titanium JavaScript - Place colored object over existing label

Tags: javascript, view, label, row, tableview

I want it to look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMXLF.jpg but it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOmMP.jpg

Here's what I have as code for it, I've tried creating a label and adding it to the row as you can see below, and also tried creating a view (createView) and adding row and label to that but that just creates a white screen.

```
var Helpers = {};
// row maker
Helpers.createNavItem = function(options) {
var footHeight=120;
if (options.title == ''){
    footHeight = 40;
}

var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:footHeight,
    title: options.title,
    backgroundImage: options.backgroundImage,
    font:{
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18},
    color: '#1d1d1d',
    backgroundColor:'#b6e2e2',
    zIndex: 1
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    bottom: 0,
    height: 20,
    width: 'fill',
    backgroundColor: '#b6e2e2',
    opacity: 50,
    zIndex: 2
});

row.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    tab1.open(options.page);
});
return row;
return row.add(label);
};
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this try using the following code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
width: Ti.UI.FILL,
height: Ti.UI.FILL,
backgroundColor: "white",
layout: "vertical"
});

createMenuItem = function(title){
var menuView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: 120,
    backgroundColor:'pink',

});
var titleView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,      
    height: 40,
    bottom: 0,      
    opacity: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#b6e2e2",
    layout: "horizontal"
});
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    top: 6,
    left: 15,
    text: title,
    font:{
        fontFamily: "Helvetica",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 18
    }
}); 
var border = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,      
    height: 4,
    bottom: 0,  
    backgroundColor: "white"
}); 
titleView.add(label);
menuView.add(titleView);
menuView.add(border);
win.add(menuView);
win.open();
//add event listeners below
};

var array = ["News", "1 Million Cups", "More Events"];
for(var i in array) 
    createMenuItem(array[i]);
```

Replace the pink background by your images.